# On click close Shadowbox and scroll to parent div

Tags: javascript, shadowbox

When clicking on a object inside Shadowbox, I want to close the iFrame, and scroll down to the a div in the parent page.

```
function ShadowClose() {
    window.parent.Shadowbox.close();
   $.scrollTo($('div#myDiv'), 500);
}
```

This is what I've tried so far, but it doesn't even close Shadowbox.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `ShadowClose` is being called?

Comment: @sroes This is what I have from the html that opens with Shadowbox `<div onClick="ShadowClose()">CLICK AND CLOSE</div>` Is that right?

Comment: And `ShadowClose` is defined in the iframe itself? Otherwise you'd have to call `top.ShadowClose()` in the onclick (and also remove window.parent from the Shadowbox.close() call).

Comment: I added `top.ShadowClose()` and removed `window.parent` but it didn't do anything. I defined the script inside the iFrame, and now it closes Shadowbox. But `$.scrollTo($('div#myDiv'), 500);` still doesn't work, I guess because it's not on the parent anymore.

Comment: And what if you change it to: `top.$.scrollTo(top.$('div#myDiv'), 500);`?

Comment: This is what I have so far, and still all it does it close it.

`<div id="mydiv" onClick="ShadowClose()">Close</div>
</div>
<script>
function ShadowClose() {
window.parent.Shadowbox.close();
setTimeout(scrollTo, 1500);
$.scrollTo(top.$('div#div'), 500);
}
</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the DIV before you close Shadowbox.

```
function ShadowClose() {
    $.scrollTo($('div#myDiv'), 500);
    window.parent.Shadowbox.close();
}
```